# How to create normally distributed random numbers in PHP with given standard deviation(sigma)?

Tags: php, math, random

I need normally distributed random numbers. Therefore I implemented the Polar Method like its mentioned here:

[Polar Method](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar-Methode)

That's working good. But my problem is it only gives me standard normally distributed random numbers. But I also need some with another standard deviation(sigma).

So I would need this generator to generate normally distributed random numbers with a given standard deviation(sigma).

At the moment I am only able to create something like the blue one (standard):
[Graphics](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Normalverteilung.svg/350px-Normalverteilung.svg.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard normally distributed random numbers have a standard deviation equal to 1.  If you just multiply those random numbers by X, where X is a positive number, then you create normally distributed numbers which have a standard deviation equal to X :-).

Comment: That worked great and it's very easy. Thank you.

Is this linear transformation?

Comment: @user1851634 I guess you could call it a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). It allows you to create random numbers of any distribution.

The basic idea is to take the density function of your desired distribution and integrate it. This gives you a CDF (cumulative distribution function). The horizontal x-axis shows the values and the vertical y-axis shows the probability that a random value is less or equal to its corresponding x-value and ranges between 0 and 1.

Then you take a stream of random numbers which are evenly distributed between 0 and 1, use them as y-values and look up the corresponing x-values. The stream of x-values will then be distributed as you had wished. This means you actually need the inverse of the CDF to look up the x-value. Hence "inverse" transform sampling.

It is not trivial to compute the ICDF for a normal distribution with given sigma, but you can look it up.

Comment: Thank you also for your fast and detailed answer.